# Dynamic component generation in Angular 9 with constructor parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, components

**Below is the component generation code. The problem is that I cannot find a solution how to pass the value to the constructor.**

**Original code:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tcejuo

```
private addComponent(template: string) {
    class TemplateComponent {

      @ViewChild('target', {static: false, read: ViewContainerRef}) public target;

      constructor() {
      }

      public myMethod() {
        // do something     
      }
    }

    class TemplateModule {
      @ViewChild('target', {static: false, read: ViewContainerRef}) public target;
    }

    const componentType = Component({template: template + '<div #target></div>'})(TemplateComponent)

    const componentModuleType = NgModule({declarations: [componentType]})(TemplateModule)

    const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(componentModuleType);
    const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
        comp.componentType === componentType
    );
    this.container.createComponent(factory);
  }
```

**If you edit the constructor parameters in the Template Component class (for example private render: Renderer2) it starts to generate an error:**

> **This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection**
>   **because its dependency at index 0 of the parameter list is invalid.**

**Please help solve this problem.**

Answer (score 0):

you need to import Renderer2 from @angular/core

import { Component, VERSION, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, NgModule, Compiler, AfterViewInit ,Renderer2} from '@angular/core'

Comment: This solution does not work for me since I am importing the component and the error persists.